# Mediaplayer.OnCompleted() is called on a livestream- only in Samsung devices

Tags: android, media-player, samsung-mobile

I streaming a live radio. Radio works fine in all devices. But on Samusung device`(Android OS- 4.2.2)`, radio stops after 20-25 minutes. On debugging, I found that call goes to `Mediaplayer.OnCompleted()` method. But In all other devices, radio works properly. And inside `OnCompleted()` -just for testing, I started the media player again and radio continues to play and again stops after 20-25 mins. What can be the problem. Is there anything specific to samsung devices.

Comment: It could very well be a Samsung or device specific bug, or something on that specific version  of Android.  But it seems like you have a workaround, I'd just use that.

Comment: @Gabe Sechanm, workaround -Are you refering to starting the media player, when onCompleted() gets called..?

Comment: Yes.  Its probably worth googling for something better, but you can use that worse case.  I wasn't able to find any other reports in a quick search.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan,But that's not a right solution right. What if the stream is actually completed...?

Comment: Why I called it a work around :)  Sometimes software is just buggy.  If it is only happening on one device, you can restrict that behavior to only that device.